# Gravity forms pre-selected choices checkboxes field

Tags: wordpress, select, checkbox, gravityforms

I am using Gravity forms with one Radio Button and one Checkboxes field they both have same choices.
What I need is when my user chooses a choice on Radio Button, this choice is automatically pre-selected on the Checkboxes field.
He doesn't have to select it again.

I saw I have to use some filter, for example, the one below, but I cannot succeed to customize it in order to do what I need.

If someone could help me he will save my life.

```
<?php

# Make sure to replace {id} with your form's id
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_{id}', 'my_populate_checkbox' );

function my_populate_checkbox( $form ) {

/**
* Loop through form fields
*
* Note we are using the `$field` array as a direct reference using `&`. 
* This means that changing its value will within the loop will 
* change the corresponding `$form` array item
*/
foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

# Make sure to change `1` to the ID of the checkbox field that you want to pre-populate
if( 1 === $field->id ) {

  /**
   * Loop through the choices for this checkbox
   *
   * Note again that we are passing `$choice` by reference in order to change the 
   * corresponding array item within the `$field` array
   */
  foreach( $field->choices as &$choice ) {

    /**
     * If this choice has a value of 'red' or 'blue', then make sure the checkbox is pre- 
   checked
     * by setting the `isSelected` parameter to `true`
     */

    if( 'red' === $choice['value'] || 'blue' === $choice['value'] ) {
      $choice['isSelected'] = true;
    }
   } # end foreach: $field->choices
   } # end if: $field->id equals 1
   } # end foreach: $form['fields']

    # return the altered `$form` array to Gravity Forms
   return $form;

    } # end: my_populate_checkbox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad that worked for you, Jean.

For other folks needing to do this, we've written a full walkthrough on the process along with an easy-to-follow use-case.

[How to Check Checkboxes (and Other Choice-based Fields) Conditionally](https://gravitywiz.com/how-to-check-checkboxes-and-other-choice-based-fields-conditionally/)

Here's a quick crash course:

1. **Create a Mapping Form**

   Create a form that will be used to keep track of which checkboxes should be checked when a given option (in another field) is selected.
2. **Submit Form Entries**

   Now you'll go through and do some data entry. Select the trigger option and then select each checkbox that should be checked for that option.
3. **Duplicate the Mapping Form**

   Next, you'll create a new form based on your mapping form. This is the form that your users would actually interact with. The mapping form is just for you.
4. **Map Your Fields**

   Lastly, use [Populate Anything](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/) to dynamically checked (i.e. populate the value) of your Checkbox field based on the option selected and the checkboxes checked for that option from your mapping form.

Answer (score 0):

Thank [Gravity Wiz](https://gravitywiz.com/) team for answering to my question. Here a video to explain how to do so: https://www.loom.com/share/f20184e287be49e89116d4c641c77c11

The idea is simple: 
1- you have to have the Gravity Perks: Populate Anything installed 
2- you have to map 2 forms: One with Data and the one which will receive the Data (this one contained your form) 
3- these 2 forms have to have the same fields 
4- on the mapping form you have to create entries, corresponding to your need

It is a little bit tricky but working perfectly for me